# how to use animate.css and viewportchecker with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, hidden, animate.css

I'm using bootstrap in a website but can not use animate.css and viewportchecker to create animations like this http://www.web2feel.com/freeby/scroll-effects/index4.html as all of the elements disappear permanently after adding the class hidden like this

```
jQuery('.row.homeCats').addClass("hide").viewportChecker({
    classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeInDown',
    offset: 100
});
```

this is the same page with bootstrap css and js files included http://goo.gl/AipVzD you can seenothing is showing up at all

I've tried applying the hidden class to multiple elements but I get the same result. The animation works normally without bootstrap with the same elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstraps hidden class is:

```
.hidden {
 display: none !important;
visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

So of course it hides everything.
But there is no "hidden" class in animate.css. I'm not sure why you need it at all but why not make your own class if you need to hide something?

**ADDENDUM**

Since your question is actually about viewportchecker not animate.css, here is a solution:

Use this for your CSS (edited)

```
 .hideme{
 opacity:0;
 }
 .visible{
 opacity:1;
 }
```

and this for your js (edited):

```
jQuery('.row.homeCats').addClass("hideme").viewportChecker({
classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeInDown',
offset: 100
});
```

Comment: Yes I know bootstrap uses .hidden class so I'm asking how to make divs appear like this http://www.web2feel.com/freeby/scroll-effects/index4.html as you see targeted divs are hidden by default then they show up with animation while scrolling

Comment: Your question was about animate.css (you shoule edit it), which is not the issue, it is viewportChecker.js you need to change.

Comment: still the same problem nothing appears at all so is there someway to make animations like in the example with bootstrap without having the problem of hiding elements? Thanks for your effort and your help

Comment: A link or jsfiddle will help. Also, change your offset and see if it makes a difference. Do you have a visible class in your CSS?

Comment: Yes I just used the same css above but everything is still hidden and there's a link in the post to an example. I can use animate.css as normal but can't hide elements then show them up that's the problem

Comment: Your link shows it working on an example site. The link people need to help you is to link to what is not working, i.e., your code! Can't really help you with the limited info you are providing.

Comment: Yes and I mentioned that all what I did was just including bootstrap css and js files (not working example included in the updated post). Thanks for your interest.

Comment: I see the problem. I forgot that Bootstrap has a hide class also that is display:none when you need opacity:0. Change the css and js as I have edited above so the class hide is not used.

Comment: works great thank you so much. I really appreciate your effort.